# java file reading and storing it in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, file-read

I was trying to read a .txt file and wanted to store it in a hasmap(String, List). But when it tried to store the values were overwritten with the last value.

```
    String filePath = "D:/liwc_new.txt";
    HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    String line;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String key = null;
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

    //putting words in key and cat strings in value of  map
    int count = 0;
    String cats[]= null;
    value.clear();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] parts = line.split(":", 2);
        value.clear();
        count++;
        key = parts[0].trim();
        cats=parts[1].split(", ");

        for(int i=0;i<cats.length;i++) {
            cats[i]=cats[i].trim();
            cats[i]=cats[i].replace("[", "");
            cats[i]=cats[i].replace("]", "");
            value.add(cats[i]);
        }

        map.put(key, value);

        //map.put(key, value);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure someone would point you to the exact problem. In the mean time, try to debug your code to find out the exact issue. May be you would get it faster.

Comment: And be sure to "accept" the answers that help you when you have your question resolved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();` should be moved to the first line of your while loop and both calls to `clear` removed.

The reason they are getting overwritten is you only ever allocate one list and put it in every value of the k:v pair of the map. So for every category, you have the same list, and the contents of that list are cleared and rebuilt every time a new line is read. So every value will have the contents of whatever was added after the last `clear`.

On the other hand, if you create a new list with each iteration, each category will have it's *own* list, what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the second occurrence of

```
value.clear();
```